# Javascript show/hide - I don't want it to hide the entire element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably a fairly easy question, but I'm new to JavaScript and jquery....

I have a website with a basic show/hide toggle. The show/hide function I'm using is here:
http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/jquery-show-hide-multiple-elements/

So here's my question..... I would really like the first 5-10 words of the toggled section to always be visible.  Is there some way I can change it so that it doesn't hide the entire element, but hides all but the first few words of the element?

Here's a screenshot of what I would like it to do:
http://answers.alchemycs.com/mobile/images/capture.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring),I did a sample demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NCg9L/35/) ,based on your screenshot

```
<div class="toggle">ShowHide</div>
<div class="content">some content some content  some content  some content  some content <br/> some content  some content  some content </div>
<div class="toggle">ShowHide</div>
<div class="content">some content some content  some content  some content  some content <br/> some content  some content  some content </div>
```

here is javascript/jquery code

```
jQuery.fn.myToggle = function(selector, count) {
    var methods = {
        toggle: function(selector, count) {
            if ($(selector).is(':visible')) {
                var span = $('<span>');
                span.text($(selector).text().substr(0, count) + "...");
                span.insertAfter($(selector));
                $(selector).hide();
            }
            else {
                $(selector).show();
                $(selector).next('span').hide();
            }
        }
    };
    $(this).each(function() {
        methods.toggle($(this).next(selector), count);
        $(this).click(function(evt) {
            methods.toggle($(this).next(selector), count);
        });
    });
};
$(function() {
    $('.toggle').myToggle('.content', 3);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  This looks wonderful - I'll go play with it on my site and see what happens....

Comment: I've tinkered with the code and I almost have it doing everything I need it to do.  My only problem is that when you load the page, everything is visible - how do I make it default to hidden?

Comment: It looks like this code only works when there is only one div to toggle - if you make multiple toggle divs, they all show or all hide at once.

Comment: You can easily do that by padding relative container using jquery,I have updated the code ,you can have look at it,http://jsfiddle.net/NCg9L/20/

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you so much!  And from messing with your code, I did learn a little bit along the way.  Thank you!

Comment: Whoops, I spoke too soon.  If you put different content into each hidden content div, when the content is hidden, each div shows the first characters of the first hidden content div, instead of showing the unique content of each div.  After you show and then hide them again, it has the appropriate content.

Answer (score 4):

There are many different implementation possibilities:

1. You can divide the contents up into the first part and the second part (two separate spans or divs inside your main object) and hide only the child object that represents the second part, not hide the parent object.
2. Rather than hide the object at all, you can set its height to only show the first part (with overflow: hidden)
3. Change the contents of the main object to only have the first part as the contents (requires you to maintain the full contents somewhere else so you can restore it when expanded again).

Here's a working example of option 1: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CTzsP/.

Comment: 2. ... and [text-overflow: elipsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow).

Comment: @Rup - if that's the desired look and you're OK with that only working in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to either:

- Put in a span/etc. after the first *n* words, and only hide that part, or
- Change the viewable region, or
- Replace or toggle the span/etc. with the "collapsed" view.

The last is a bit more customizable; using two separate elements allows trivial games to be played (showing an image, for example, like a little curly arrow) without modifying adding/removing DOM elements.

I tend towards the last because it's simple and obvious, but that's a personal preference, and really isn't as true as it used to be.

Comment: All of these suggestions are useful, but I'm new enough to JavaScript that I need some guidance on how to actually implement them.  Can you give me some code or tell me which functions I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using css properties only instead of mangling the dom.

http://jsfiddle.net/AYre3/4/

Now if you want some sort of animation happening as well you'll probably need to do a bit of measurement along the way.

Comment: I can get this to work just fine on jsfiddle, but when I put it on my site, I get the following error:  `$("#list").on('click', 'a', function() { `   Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think I was getting the error because my site had jquery 1.6.2.  I switched to 1.7.1.  Now I'm not getting any error messages, but nothing happens when I click the "Show/Hide" button.  Any suggestions?